# How do you know how much effort to do and for how long?

Tags: exercise-technique, pain, stretching, flexibility

When stretching and flexing muscles, How much should I push my muscles and for how long before I take a few seconds break?
I usualy push as far as I can, and for as much as time as I can, and only if it really hurts I stop.
It can hurt even few hours later, so it's a little hint I'm doing it wrong, so I hope you could explain, how should I stretch?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe helpful to state your specific goals e.g. trying to build up flexibility to help some specific sport, or score well on a given fitness test, or prevent injuries when doing X...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what kind of stretching you're doing, and what kind of stretching program you're on. I recommend buying Stretching Scientifically by Tom Kurz and reading about the topic in detail.

Comment: Thanks, but to be honest I'm not looking for reading a whole book. would you happen to know how does it work with the spine and back? I kind of need a good, quick answer that I could follow easily.

Comment: @Ken - it isn't that simple a subject, there are so many variables that you do need to either fully research this or work with a trainer to help you identify what levels you can take stretching to

Comment: @RoryAlsop I see. thanks for helping me realize.